# div with only border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a div over another div to create a border.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30396291/LOL/borderproblem.png) is an example:

Now I have a problem: if I put the mouse over the image I get the focus on the `div` with the border only (for ex., if I want right click and save img) but the `div` is empty all the time (is used only for the border) how i can ignore the center part of the `div`?

I used a `div` because I place the border over the image/other stuff and I can't have the same result using the original border (is placed outside the image and I get a white space from the border and the image).

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z3u3/2/) the dimension aren't right. (I place the border with js code)

```
img = $('<div style="position:absolute; width: ' + ($(this) .outerWidth(true) +  
    leagueBorders[templeague].width) + 'px; height: ' + ($(this) .outerHeight(true) +  
    leagueBorders[templeague].height) + 'px; max-width: none; top: '+  
    ($(this).position().top + leagueBorders[templeague].top) +'px; left: '+  
    ($(this).position().left + leagueBorders[templeague].left) +'px;"  
    class="'+leagueBorders[templeague].classe+'"></div>');`
```

But you can easily see the problem. If you right click on the image you get the right click menu of a empty space instead of the image options.
if I a text with a scroll bar (instead of the image) I can't use the scroll bar.

Comment: WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY THAT TITLE ?

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: reproduce it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

A div isn't enmpty just because you don't see anything in it. A div can have a transparent content, it doesn't mean that ti's empty. It's like a transparent layer. That's why it takes the focus. You should use css border properties to fit your borders to the image. Or, you should wrap your image in a container (a div) and apply specific css rules to this container, so that your borders will fit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your HTML tags and use CSS to do all the graphical work.
Make sure `img` tag is inside `div` and then use the following CSS.
[SEE PICTURE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amGYS.jpg)

```css
.rank-Platino {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 95 80 95 80;
  border-image-width: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
  border-image-source: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30396291/LOL/border/plat-border.png");
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<a class="avatar">
  <div style="position:absolute; width: 90px; max-width: none; top: 0px; left: 0px" class="rank-Platino rank-border">
    <img height=163 width=90 class="user_summoner_icon PLATINUM rank-border"
      src="http://www.mobafire.com/images/champion/skins/portrait/rammus-full-metal.jpg"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS when working with borders, like this:

```
border-size:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
```